# How to call runningSum function and print it?

Tags: arrays, integer

package Package;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Cars {

```
public int[] runningSum(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    int[] res = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      sum = sum+nums[0];
      res[i]=sum;
    }
    return res;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] a = {1,2,3,4};

Cars arr = new Cars();
System.out.println(arr.runningSum(a));
}
```

}

//output i'm getting is [I@e580929]
//output i want is [1,3,6,10]

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you are trying to do by *sum = sum+nums[0];* after the loop. But the solution below works!

```
 public int[] runningSum(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    int[] res = new int[nums.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
       
        sum = sum + nums[i]; 
        res[i] = sum;
    }
    return res;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr.runningSum(a)));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.